# Is there any way to add/customize in VSTF the Test Runs colums/information?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, customization

As a test engineer we always find the lack of info in the Test Runs tab too confusing and useless when it should be one of the most important tab in order to know which test runs are related to which tests builds, test plans, creators, etc

However I can´t find a way to add more columns or info like in the test plan tab. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can’t add additional columns to test run in Test>Runs tab, you need to check those information in the summary of a test. (Double click a test run> Test results> double click a test)

There is a user voice that you can vote: A[dditional columns for test run in test > Runs tab](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32429438-additional-columns-for-test-run-in-test-runs-tab)